# Convert mp4 file to binary in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to convert an mp4 video file recorded with device camera to binary data so that I can upload to a site through an API. I think my conversion method is giving me corrupted data or is it the video currupted in the first place? Check this out, heres how I convert my file to binary:

```
File file = new File(videoPath);

try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int size = (int) file.length();
bytes = new byte[size];

try {
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1;) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, readNum);
        System.out.println("Read: " + readNum);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I use `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` as body request which does not mean anything to the API.

Here's how the binary data looks:

������ftypmp42��������isommp42����moov������lmvhd�����������������������U����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������@����������������������������������������������������������������,trak������\tkhd���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������@�����������8���������mdia������ mdhd����������������*���l��������������,hdlr����������������vide������������������������VideoHandle������tminf������vmhd����������������������������$dinf������dref��������������������url ����������4stbl�������stsd���������������������avc1�����������������������������������������������8��H������H����������������                               ����������&avcCB�(����gB�(����O����F���h��������pasp����������������stts��������������@�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������  ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������s�����������������(stss�������������������������� ������?������^������}������������stsz����������������������������"����#�����;+����P�����|������T����˶����������݂�����W���������������׵�����������M����������Y����ݪ���������������͉�����$����������Ź����������������z�����=�����C��������������Y����������������������'����������o�����@����������������������������������������T�����Y�����!��Kp����*\����������r�����������*����������������������Ζ�����[������������������WC�����������������������(����������������������P�����������  ����������������������������Ŭ�����  �����������������K�����������0�����������N����������������������&���������t��������Q����~{�����-�����n�����z�����������������0����������������X�����������������������������������������������������������������������������V�����������U�����������������������������Z��^U�����o����������������6�����������5�����  �����������i�����K�����������������f�����1�����������~�����3�����T�����������0�����������������9����ж�����s�����0�����A�����)�����m��������-������������J�����o����������������    �����/���������������������������?�����m�����@�����������g�����������������a�����������y�����?���������������Q����������n�����������������������4stsc��������������������������!������������������������������������������������(stco����������������*��� |���8�*��P���h�����m�����{trak������\tkhd������������������������������U������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������@��������������������������mdia������ mdhd���������������������������������������,hdlr��������������

Comment: "I'm trying to convert an mp4 video file recorded with device camera to binary data" -- an MP4 video file *is* binary data. "I think my conversion method is giving me corrupted data or is it the video currupted in the first place?" -- why do you think that you need any of this code?

Comment: @CommonsWare Because the API requires the data formated as binary

Comment: Again, the data already *is* formatted as binary.

Comment: Really? So all those weird symbols is how it should look? I thought it was corrupted because it didn't looked like that days ago and I was able to upload the file.

Comment: "So all those weird symbols is how it should look?" -- binary data cannot be examined reliably by dumping it as if it were text. Hence, it should not "look" like anything.